# About Widget size specification for each device in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I created a Flutter app based on iphoneX. So, when I ran it on another device, the size of the Widget was not what I intended due to the different screen size ratios of the devices.
So, how can we specify the Widget size in the same ratio as the standard device even for non-standard devices?

iphoneX's size
height:896.0
width:414.0
devicePixelRatio:2.0,
aspectRatio:0.46205357142857145

I specified the size of the widget by calculating as follows, but the layout collapsed.

```dart
sizedBox(
// iphoneX's devicePixelRatio = 2.0
height: MediaQuery.of(Home.scaffoldKey.currentContext!).size.height / 2.0,
width: MediaQuery.of(Home.scaffoldKey.currentContext!).size.width * 2.0,
)
```

Comment: Generally, any scaling that is driven by device width is wrong. TL;DR: use LayoutBuilder (not MediaQuery) to determine breakpoints only (side nav vs bottom nav, two columns vs three). Then use Flex widgets (Row, Column, Expanded, Spacer, etc) to lay out your text. Do not change the font size.

The way to remember this is to think back to the last time you made a web page or a desktop app wider. Did the characters get bigger? No? :) Then stop making your apps "scale" font sizes. Use width to re-layout, not re-size.

Comment: Icons of the same size will look different on different device sizes. So it seems a better way to calculate the Widget size from the device size.